# How do I set a unique key for a MODEL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models and I would like to know how to make the relationship. Must be one to one.

Comment: Read through Ruby on Rails guide on Associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Tks. This link help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the model. I used "belongs_to" in the model then have the foreign key and use has_one in another model.